# Initiate Wygwam with <p class="name">

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

When a Wygwam field gets loaded, the first thing you type is within `<p>` tags. Is it possible to make the default tag `<p class="something">`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just wrap a div around the content and use a bit of jquery to handle that. I don't think wygwam can handle this without some trickery.